# Does $\Pr[\sum X_i \ge m] \ge \Pr[\sum Y_i \ge m]$ follow from $\Pr[X_i = 1] \ge \Pr[Y_i = 1]$ for each $i$?

Tags: probability

Given independent Bernoulli random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ with
$\Pr[X_i = 1] \ge \Pr[Y_i = 1]$ for each $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Does it hold that $\Pr[\sum X_i \ge m] \ge \Pr[\sum Y_i \ge m]$ for any nonnegative $m$?
If so, how to prove it?

This question is relevant to applying some Chernoff bound. For instance, if we show Bernoulli variables $X_i$ with unknown probability distribution satisfy $\Pr[X_i = 1] \le 2/3$, then we can switch to the analysis around Bernoulli variables $Y_i$ with $\Pr[Y_i = 1] = 2/3$ and $E[\sum Y_i] = \frac{2}{3} n$.

Intuitively this seems true. But I still cannot find a proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Are your random variables maybe Bernoulli distributed and you forgot to mention it?

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes. I should mention Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: @geetha290krm I just add "Bernoulli random variables" condition. For Bernoulli random variables, if $\Pr[Y_i = 1] = 0$ for all $i$, then $\Pr[Y_i = 0] = 1$ for all $i$, then $\Pr[\sum Y_i \ge m] = 0$ for positive $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_i := P(X_i = 1)$ and $q_i := P(Y_i = 1)$. By your assumption, $q_i \leq p_i$.

In case of $q_i = 1$, let $Z_i := 0$. Otherwise, let $r_i := \frac{p_i - q_i}{1 - q_i}$ and note $0 \leq r_i \leq 1$, so that we can let $Z_i \sim Ber(r_i)$ such that $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n,Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ are jointly independent. Then, defining $\tilde{X_i} := \max \{Y_i, Z_i\}$ we have that $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ has the same distribution as $(\tilde{X_1}, \dots, \tilde{X_n})$ (check!).

Hence,
$$
P(\sum_i X_i \geq m)
= P(\sum_i \tilde{X_i} \geq m)
\geq P(\sum_i Y_i \geq m).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)).

---

For each $i \in [n] = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, define

$$ p_i = \mathrm{Pr}[X_i = 1] \qquad\text{and}\qquad q_i = \mathrm{Pr}[Y_i = 1]. $$

Now we realize the joint distributions of $(X_i)_{i\in[n]}$ and $(Y_i)_{i\in[n]}$ in a coupled way. Let $(U_i)_{i\in[n]}$ be i.i.d. uniform random variables over $[0, 1]$. Then set

$$ X'_i = \mathbf{1}[U_i \leq p_i] \qquad\text{and}\qquad Y_i = \mathbf{1}[U_i \leq q_i], $$

where $\mathbf{1}[\ldots]$ is the indicator function notation. Then we observe:

- $(X'_i)_{i\in[n]}$ has the same distribution as $(X_i)_{i\in[n]}$,
- $(Y'_i)_{i\in[n]}$ has the same distribution as $(Y_i)_{i\in[n]}$, and
- $X'_i \geq Y'_i$ for all $i \in [n]$.

Therefore $\sum_{i\in[n]} X'_i \geq \sum_{i\in[n]} Y'_i$ holds and we get

$$ \mathrm{Pr}\left[\sum_{i\in[n]} X_i \geq m \right]
= \mathrm{Pr}\left[\sum_{i\in[n]} X'_i \geq m \right]
\geq \mathrm{Pr}\left[\sum_{i\in[n]} Y'_i \geq m \right]
= \mathrm{Pr}\left[\sum_{i\in[n]} Y_i \geq m \right]. $$